# Pasar valores null de C# a sql server

Tags: c#

De momento me encuentro realizando un formulario en el cual oculto unos campos con el fin de llenarlos al editar.

El inconveniente es que al dar clic en guardar me genera un error de tipo `La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.` y es por que los campos de que he ocultado me recibe valores de tipo `ditetime`, pero como los he ocultado no les añado un valor de ese tipo de dato. Lo que requiero hacer es enviar a esos campos valores `null`. He intentado con lo siguiente pero aun no lo consigo

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxFechainicial1.Text))
   fc.fecha_cuota_inic1 = DateTime.Parse(TextBoxFechainicial1.Text);`

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxFechainicial2.Text))
   fc.fecha_cuota_inic2 = DateTime.Parse(TextBoxFechainicial2.Text);
```

de que otra forma puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Utiliza tipos nullables en la propiedad:

```
DateTime? fecha_cuota_inic1 {get; set;}
DateTime? fecha_cuota_inic2 {get; set;}
```

o de esta otra forma (es lo mismo):

```
Nullable<DateTime> fecha_cuota_inic1 {get; set;}
Nullable<DateTime> fecha_cuota_inic2 {get; set;}
```

Suponiendo, claro, que hayaa diseñado tu tabla con esos dos campos que permitan null.

EDIT
Fuente: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/

Comment: +1 Su respuesta esta bien, solo como observación puede agregar la fuente `MSDN` sobre `Nullable` , Saludos!

Comment: Hola justamente los tengo asi: `public Nullable<DateTime> fecha_cuota_inic1 { get; set; }` y `public Nullable<DateTime> fecha_cuota_inic2 { get; set; }` y la tabla la tengo diseñada para que me permita valores `null`

Comment: Puedes agregar el código donde mandas guardar los datos a la bdd?

Comment: https://codeshare.io/ark3ZY  lo he intentado de varias formas y aun no lo consigo, comparto el codigo y la forma como lo he intentado resolver

Comment: Insisto, ¿puedes agregar el código donde mandas guardar los datos a la bdd?

Answer (score 2):

Propiedades tipo null

```
DateTime? fecha_cuota_inic1 { get; set; }
DateTime? fecha_cuota_inic2 { get; set; }
```

En la clase de acceso a datos podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
var connection = new SqlConnection("stringConnection");
var command = new SqlCommand("command", connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", obj.fecha_cuota_inic1 ?? DbNull.Value);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", obj.fecha_cuota_inic2 ?? DbNull.Value);
```

El campo de la tabla que quieres modificar debe permitir valores null

Comment: lo he intentado de esta forma https://codeshare.io/ark3ZY pero no lo he logrado conseguir aun

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo solucioné dandole el valor mínimo

```
DateTime FechaNull = DateTime.MinValue;
```

ahora solo verifica

```
if (FechaNull == DateTime.MinValue)
{
...
}
```